# DexArchiveBuilderException on compilation after migrating to Gradle Plugin 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've recently upgraded our android application's gradle plugin from `2.3.3` to `3.0.0`. After resolving most of the compilation issues, I'm still plagued with the following exception:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: 
Failed to process /Users/{user}/SourceCode/Android/{project_path}/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/113.jar
```

The `{user}` and `{project_path}` fields are placeholders for the actual values.

I'm not entirely sure exactly what's happening but from the looks of the stacktrace the build is failing to dex one of our third party sdks (`Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing com/outbrain/OBSDK/HttpClient/OBHttpClient.class`). The odd thing about this though is the fact that the build works as expected if I build the project internally or if I build and generate the apks for both debug and release. Its only when I attempt to deploy the app on the emulator that I receive this error.

Any insight into why this error is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I've referred to the Google Doc (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) and I don't see anything regarding this issue.

Here's the output of the relevant stacktrace:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/{user}/SourceCode/Android/{project_path}/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/113.jar
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:550)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$1(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:488)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing com/outbrain/OBSDK/HttpClient/OBHttpClient.class

at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:143)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.convert(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:89)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:545)
... 6 more

Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: stack: underflow
at com.android.dx.cf.code.ExecutionStack.throwSimException(ExecutionStack.java:341)
at com.android.dx.cf.code.ExecutionStack.peek(ExecutionStack.java:206)
at com.android.dx.cf.code.ExecutionStack.peekType(ExecutionStack.java:241)
at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitNoArgs(Simulator.java:427)
at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:584)
at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:103)
at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:790)
at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:745)
at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:350)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:309)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:150)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:102)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.dex(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:107)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.convert(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:86)
... 7 more
```

**Edit:** Added project build.gradle to question. Note: Added placeholders for sensitive information:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/optimizely/optimizely'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to
        // react quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'

        // Kotlin Support
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.51'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    maven {
        url "http://appboy.github.io/appboy-android-sdk/sdk"
    }
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/teads/TeadsSDK-android"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    google()
}

// Test Dependencies
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
    // testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert:1.4'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.4'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.4'
}

dependencies {

    def appCompatVersion = "25.3.1"
    def playServicesVersion = "11.0.4"

    compile project(':BRShared')
    compile project(':CastCompanionLibrary-android')
    wearApp project(':wear')

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile(name: 'sharethrough-android-sdk-v4.4.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile('com.optimizely:optimizely:+@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$playServicesVersion"

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$appCompatVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$appCompatVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$appCompatVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$appCompatVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$appCompatVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$appCompatVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:2.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.19.0'

    // Facebook
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'

    // Inneractive SDK
    compile(name: 'ia-mraid-kit-release-7.0.5', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'ia-native-kit-release-7.0.5', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'ia-sdk-core-full-release-7.0.5', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'ia-video-kit-release-7.0.5', ext: 'aar')


    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.outbrain.obsdk:obsdk:2.1.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3'
    compile files('libs/bluekai.jar')

    // Reactive
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

    // ExoPlayer
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.0'

    // AdobePass
    compile files('libs/novacorps-adobepass-client-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/nebula-config-1.3.0.jar')

    // Needed in libs directory to avoid missing MVPD model compile error
    compile files('libs/android_accessenabler-1.9.1.jar')

    // Android Spin Kit UI
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'

    // Teads SDK
    compile ('tv.teads.sdk:androidsdk:2.4.14:fullRelease@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    // Material Ripple Layout
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1'

    // Moshi - JSON Object Mapping
    compile 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'

    // GIF Image Library - For Animations
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.compile_sdk_version.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion project.build_tools_version
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId {application_id}
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 31500100
        versionName {version_name}
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        minSdkVersion 19

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias {key_alias}
            keyPassword {key_password}
            storeFile file({file_name})
            storePassword {store_password}
        }
    }

buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            debuggable true

            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_FORCE_UNICORN_OFF", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_STETHO", "true"

            // These are the values for the authorities and account types.
            resValue "string", "account_type", "{application_id}.debug.accounttype"
            resValue "string", "authority", "{application_id}.debug"

            resValue "string", "about_version_build", defaultConfig.versionName
            resValue "string", "about_version_suffix", "debug"
            resValue "string", "outbrain_test_mode", "true"
            resValue "bool", "enable_view_server", "true"
            resValue "bool", "hockey_app_auto_upload", "false"

            resValue "string", "base_feed_url", {base_feed_url}
            resValue "string", "path_config", "xmldata/configuration-androidtest"

            resValue "string", "google_now_check_credentials_url", "{google_check_credentials_url}"
            resValue "string", "google_now_add_credentials_url", "{google_add_credentials_url}"
            resValue "string", "google_now_add_activity_url", "{google_add_activity_url}"

            resValue "string", "com_appboy_push_gcm_sender_id", "{sender_id}"
            resValue "string", "com_appboy_api_key", "{api_key}"
        }
        release {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_FORCE_UNICORN_OFF", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_STETHO", "false"

            // Reference them again so they get overwritten by the flavor.
            resValue "string", "account_type", "{application_id}.accounttype"
            resValue "string", "authority", "{application_id}"

            resValue "string", "about_version_build", defaultConfig.versionName
            resValue "string", "about_version_suffix", "release"
            resValue "string", "outbrain_test_mode", "false"
            resValue "bool", "enable_view_server", "false"
            resValue "bool", "hockey_app_auto_upload", "true"

            resValue "string", "base_feed_url", "{base_feed_url}"
            resValue "string", "path_config", "xmldata/configuration-androidv4"
            resValue "string", "google_now_check_credentials_url", "{google_check_credentials_url}"
            resValue "string", "google_now_add_credentials_url", "{google_add_credentials_url}"
            resValue "string", "google_now_add_activity_url", "{google_add_activity_url}"

            resValue "string", "com_appboy_push_gcm_sender_id", "{sender_id}"
            resValue "string", "com_appboy_api_key", "{api_key}"
        }
        livesim {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            versionNameSuffix '-LIVE-SIM'
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_FORCE_UNICORN_OFF", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_STETHO", "false"

            // Reference them again so they get overwritten by the flavor.
            resValue "string", "account_type", "{application_id}.accounttype"
            resValue "string", "authority", "{application_id}"

            resValue "string", "about_version_build", defaultConfig.versionName
            resValue "string", "about_version_suffix", "release"
            resValue "string", "outbrain_test_mode", "false"
            resValue "bool", "enable_view_server", "false"
            resValue "bool", "hockey_app_auto_upload", "true"

            resValue "string", "base_feed_url", "{base_feed_url}"
            resValue "string", "path_config", "xmldata/configuration-androidv4"
            resValue "string", "google_now_check_credentials_url", "{google_check_credentials_url}"
            resValue "string", "google_now_add_credentials_url", "{google_add_credentials_url}"
            resValue "string", "google_now_add_activity_url", "{google_add_activity_url}"

            resValue "string", "com_appboy_push_gcm_sender_id", "{sender_id}"
            resValue "string", "com_appboy_api_key", "{api_key}"

            // Fallback for sub projects
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        livesim.setRoot('build-types/livesim')
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
        outputFileName = "{Application_Name}-" + (buildType == "release" || buildType == "livesim" ? "release-" : "") + "${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: Added in the edit above

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer to my question but in case anyone is still searching for an answer, I'll post my solution here:

It turns out the issue was installing the debug build on the emulator/physical device with the Advanced Profiling field enabled. This is a feature that was enabled in Android Studio 3.0 that allows developers to get more precise and detailed information from whats output from the Android Profiler.

The description for the requirements are a little misleading imho. It identifies that its required for API versions **less than** ver. 26 but that's not the case (at least for me it wasn't). It seems to build successfully only on API versions **greater than** ver. 26 if you choose to enable it. It may have something to do with the updated Multi-Dex support library where it hasn't flushed out all the methods by the time the Advanced Profiler requires them but there doesn't seem to be any details on whats going on.

If you're running your build on a device less than ver. 26 (i.e. Android O), try disabling the field in your run configurations (its located under the Profiling tab within the Edit Run Configurations window).

[Advanced Profiling Field in Run Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykfLH.png)

Hope that helps!